# VSTS git repo error: has conflicting settings policies configured

Tags: azure-devops

I have a VSTS repo which was working fine. Now for some unknown reason (possibly when someone was changing permissions on the entire team project?), when trying to clone it to another machine, I get error - The most detailed one is from commandline:

```
> git clone (repo-url)
Cloning into '(path)'...
remote: The Git repository with ID (guid) has conflicting settings policies configured. You must remove one of the policies with conflicting settings.
fatal: unable to access '(url-repo)': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

Additional attempts:

- `Manage Repositories => (myrepo) => options tab` - same error
- `Manage Repositories => (myrepo) => master => Branch Policies` - I *sometimes* get the same error, and sometimes get the policy page. However, even if I change stuff in the policy page and save, I still get the same error when cloning.

How can I reset these conflicting setting policies?

Comment: Can you access to the cloned URL manually in web page? And what's the team and group that your account in (Security Tab) and what's the branch policies did the repo set?

Comment: Can you share all the policy settings?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: Yes, I get the VSTS repo page, with the `Fork` and `Clone` buttons missing, and a `X failed` where `Set up release` button usually is. My account is in `Contributors` group, but the project admin has specific entry giving her all privileges, and she gets the same error.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: As I wrote, when I go to Policy Settings pages, I usually get a `500 internal server error`, with the same original error like the clone command (`conflicting settings policies`).

Comment: @Jonathan What if you ask the administrator move your account from Contributor to a new created group. If you have sufficient permissions, the Fork and Clone button should be displayed. And if you still can not clone the repo, you can ask the administrator to provide the branch policies you are applying.

Comment: Thanks. The administrator is getting the exact same error and behavior like I'm getting, including missing Clone/Fork buttons and error messages. That's why I think the repo is somehow corrupt at the VSTS level.